# ArcGIS - Spatial ETL Tool - Checking fields in input shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-etl, data-interoperability

How to check if the input file fields have the expected name and type?

Which transformer will be useful to validate names and types of attributes of reader.

edit:
I have a shapefile that transforms using ETL to gdb.
But at first I want to check if the attributes of this shapefile is required by me names and types.
For example: I want to check if the file road.shp, which is my "reader" has attributes:
'NAME' [type: char, width: 265], 
'NUMBER' [type: integer].
How to control input shapefile when I will have a next file to be transformed.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 with FME 2014

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  Also, you talk about fields but do not tell us what format the tables they belong to are stored in.